# how to disable or block all ui interactiablity in canvas without any blocker image?

Tags: unity, gui

I need to disable any interaction from UI  for some reason. I know there are some approaches like using a blocker image to disable the whole UI but I don't want to use that. I need to know is there any property or feature in the UI event system to temporarily disable each button and any input?

Comment: Did you look at using a [Canvas Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) ?

Comment: Depends on your use case. You could disable the Event System and none of your buttons or input fields are going to work. But what is going to enable your UI again?

Comment: @Zibelas maybe enabling it again :)

Comment: Of course they will work again by enabling it again. If it is a timed blocking or scripted (like showing a tutorial in the ui) you won't have a problem.